# Docker Running the Java -JAR file to create Cassandra KeySpaces. But its not creating

Tags: docker, cassandra, dockerfile

I tried to run the CMD "java -jar /tmp/migration.jar update_schema atlas " to create the Keyspace in the cassandra.  But its not creating any keyspaces in cassandra.   But if i run same command in the command line its creating any idea whats the issue?

My dockerfile is as follows 
    'FROM tomcat:8-jre8

```
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV COMMAND="update"
ENV ARGS="--logLevel=debug"

WORKDIR  /usr/local/tomcat/

ADD /migration.jar /tmp
ADD atlas_migration.sh /usr/local/bin/atlas_migration.sh
CMD ["/bin/sh", "/usr/local/bin/atlas_migration.sh"]

CMD ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/tmp/migration.jar","update_schema", "atlas"]
CMD java -jar /tmp/migration.jar update_schema atlas

ENV CATALINA_OPTS "-Xmx256m -Xms192m"

EXPOSE 8085

CMD ./bin/catalina.sh start  &&   tail -f ./logs/catalina.out'
```

Answer (score 1):

`CMD` is for specifying the command the container should run when it starts. If you want to run a command **during** the build, so the state after execution is persisted in the image, you need to use `RUN`.

`COPY` is also preferable to `ADD`, so the relevant instructions should be:

```
COPY /migration.jar /tmp
COPY atlas_migration.sh /usr/local/bin/atlas_migration.sh
RUN /usr/local/bin/atlas_migration.sh
RUN ["java","-jar","/tmp/migration.jar","update_schema", "atlas"]
```